# How to show value that has column with multiple value in another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have A table:
[image]

Then B table:
[image]

Last one, C table:
[image]

I need to show them to be like this:

```
performance_id | quiz_id
________________________
22             | 65
23             | null
24             | 43
25             | null
```

I tried join but it show wrong result. It not show quiz id. I tried this:

```
SELECT A.performance_id, C.quiz_id 
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON A.performance_id=B.performance_id 
LEFT JOIN C ON B.phc_id = C.phc_id 
group BY A.performance_id;
```

result:
[image]

Help me,thanks

Comment: Show what you have tried and what the Output is

Comment: please see my edited question @Reno

Comment: please see my edited question @Jens

Comment: remove Group by or Change your select to `SELECT A.performance_id, group_concat(C.quiz_id )
FROM A 
...` because you get more than one quiz_id

Comment: Check [**SQLFiddle DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8eeb7/1). I've used your query sql and got what you want to fetch.

Comment: thanks @Jens , `group_concat` is what i need

Comment: @NikeYulistiaAngreni Have added my comment as answer. Feel free to accept and/or upvote it

Comment: done @Jens .Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group_concat`:

```
SELECT A.performance_id, group_concat(C.quiz_id) 
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON A.performance_id=B.performance_id 
LEFT JOIN C ON B.phc_id = C.phc_id 
group BY A.performance_id;
```

Because you get more than one `quiz_id`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT A.performance_id, group_concat(C.quiz_id) 
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON A.performance_id = B.performance_id 
LEFT JOIN C ON B.phc_id = C.phc_id 
group BY A.performance_id;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6411fb/3)